# Is transducer a signal processing device

Tags: signal-processing

I know transducer is the device which could transfer one type energy into another type. But I am not sure whether transducer can change the form of signal.

Comment: A transducer can change the shape of a signal (depending on the signal and on the transducer, of course).  For example, a transducer will probably have low- or high-pass filter properties: wanted or unwanted.  [What had prompted this question in the first place, I wonder?]

Comment: thank you for the answer. i am just touching the signal processing and data acquisition system. I was confused the functionality of transducer.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=transducer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Am unsure exactly what you're getting at, but I'm thinking of transducers for gyroscope - lots of different approaches. A crystal has piezoelectric properties that can yield voltage proportional to acceleration in a direct way.
 But a crystal can also be [used in an oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrating_structure_gyroscope), relying on coriolis effect to form a gyroscope. Innovative forms of resonators may null various disturbing effects like temperature. Frequency and/or phase is often easier to measure than a direct voltage measurement, and may give a more sensitive result without drift problems. Or drift might be pushed into a different domain.